# Which is more secure against packet injection?

Tags: network, penetration-test, router

I was wondering how secure the network of my service provider is.

Which network is more secured against file injection, password cracking, or brute force login: a network using a captive portal, WPA2-PSK/ENTERPRISE, or using a proxy server?

And is it possible to use a proxy server and WPA2-ENTERPRISE simultaneously on the same network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which network is more secured against file injection, password cracking, or brute force login: a network using a captive portal, WPA2-PSK/ENTERPRISE, or using a proxy server?

While your question is not clear enough in this regard the choice of options you give suggests that you look at security from the perspective of the operator of the network who wants to identify and also protect its users. Because as a user you don't usually have a choice - you just need to accept what the operator gives you.

All of the three options can be used for authentication of the client and it looks like that this is what you care about. Password cracking with or without using brute force works with all of these. How fast this gets detected  depends on the security measures employed by the authentication backend and how often the front end allows a client to try another authentication.

But while a captive portal and WPA2-PSK/ENTERPRISE essentially authorize the client computer a proxy authorizes a client program (basic authentication) or a user on the system (NTLM in a windows network). This makes a difference if you have multiple users on the system and it also makes a difference how easy some other user can spoof it: with a system based authentication it is usually enough to overtake the IP address and maybe also the MAC of an already authorized but currently inactive client.

As for file or packet injection: none of the solutions addresses this problem in a specific way. While WPA2 encrypts the Wifi connection the other options work at other levels, i.e. would work with encrypted Wifi too but also with open Wifi, cable .... Thus it is not possible to compare them on these level. Apart from that none of the options does anything against ARP spoofing, source IP spoofing or similar attacks which are used for sniffing and packet injection and modification.

> And is it possible to use a proxy server and WPA2-ENTERPRISE simultaneously on the same network?

Yes, it is possible to combine these.

Answer (score 1):

In short, this looks like this:

- WiFi without password is totally insecure. You can use VPN (not proxy) but then it's hard to use VPN on all devices.
- WPA2-PSK (Personal) is OK except Evil Twin Attack as long as you have something like 14 character, random password with upper, lower-case characters and numbers. Some go with 12 character length if the password is truly random.
- WPA2-EAP (Enterprise) if usually most secure and resilient to Evil Twin Attack. There's some security risk in EAP protocols and software stacks on your systems involved in it, however this is much harder to do and it can be patched once the flaw is found so it's not broken by design.
- WPA2-PSK/Enterprise is not really something really common. It may be it's some sort of misinformation because this standard haven't been adopted.
- Captive portals can be used with any of the above variants. It's more suitable for the Hotels for example

For the convenience, security and compability you could go with WPA2-EAP/PAP which is using login and password, so you can enter these on every device.
Captive portal is not also very secure because someone can do MITM on it even with fake SSL cert. It's good for customers who can logon with their Facebook account for example. With WPA2-EAP/PAP you'd get login and password so then you just enter it on Smartphone, Laptop etc.

You can use VPN on any kind of WiFi network. If you plan connecting multiple devices you could setup dedicated router which would handle the VPN for all devices but this would be quite complicated and hard to get it working in stable fashion on the start. I think if you can get WPA2-EAP or good PSK key then you'd be just fine without VPN, however if you do not trust your provider you can get one as well, starting from your laptop for example, using it on the mobiles is quite an over-kill.